# Windows 7 64bit crashes everytime I try to run Windows 7 Phone emulator

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, emulator

I have Vs 2010, Vs 2012, Windows phone 7.1 & 7.8 SDK on my computer and everytime I make a default project in Vs 2010 and try to run the emulator my computer crashes.

This was the last error.

```
A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage
to your computer.

The problem seems to be caused by the following file: win32k.sys



If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen,
restart your computer. If this screen appears again, follow
these steps:

Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
If this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software manufacturer
for any Windows updates you might need.

If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware
or software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.
If you need to use safe mode to remove or disable components, restart
your computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup Options, and then
select Safe Mode.

Technical Information:

*** STOP: 0x00000101 (0x0000000000000031, 0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff88002fd7180, 
0x0000000000000003)

*** win32k.sys - Address 0xfffff960001cc36b base at 0xfffff96000040000 DateStamp 
0x50e64bda
```

This was the error before

A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage
to your computer.

The problem seems to be caused by the following file: msahci.sys

```
If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen,
restart your computer. If this screen appears again, follow
these steps:

Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
If this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software manufacturer
for any Windows updates you might need.

If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware
or software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.
If you need to use safe mode to remove or disable components, restart
your computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup Options, and then
select Safe Mode.

Technical Information:

*** STOP: 0x00000101 (0x0000000000000031, 0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff88002f65180, 
0x0000000000000002)

*** msahci.sys - Address 0xfffff88000cad739 base at 0xfffff88000ca9000 DateStamp 
0x4ce7a416
```

Comment: What CPU and motherboard is this? Are you overclocking or overvolting the CPU or memory?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a hardware problem with the CPU. Make sure the CPU isn't overheating. Make sure the BIOS supports the CPU. Upgrading the BIOS may help. It could be a motherboard chipset driver. You can try installing the latest drivers for your chipset.

Microsoft says malware or a failing hard drive could cause this error. So I'd check for that just to be on the safe side. I'd also boot from a [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org) CD and let it run for a few hours to rule out some more hardware issues.

Comment: Well I went ahead and just formatted the computer and started over so far not getting those problems anymore. Hopefully it is the end of the problems. I just bought a new motheboard, new cpu(i5), new heatsink fan, 8 gigs of ram and new HDD because my last cpu was over heating. I probably will do a memtest just to be on the same side.